# Is it possible to club 2 or more Scripts in Python(spyder)?

Tags: python

I have more than 5 scripts which will perform different operations as and when required. Some Scripts does copying of files to excel while some helps in Plotting of Various Graph.

Is there a way in Python where in i can combine all multiple scripts to One script and when i run it i will choose which script to run.
Eg: Lets us say script named as abc,xyz,pqr,fgh etc. So i will club all those script to 1 script then When i will run i will choose which script i want to execute like abc or xyz or pqr etc

Comment: If your scripts contain functions, you could import them all into a `main.py` and then delegate function calls.

Comment: Do you want to literally combine them into a single file, or do you just want to be able to make a single command execution to run combinations of the various scripts?  Are there parameters involved with these scripts, and if so, how do you think that should be dealt with when running multiple scripts?

Comment: My main objective is rather than opening 5 scripts and run them separately. Is it possible i will club all 5 scripts and when i Run it ,It should ask which script do u want to run then i will choose what i want to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a wrapper script that obtains the necessary parameters, either on the command line or by querying the user, and then uses the `subprocess` module to run each script in exactly the same way as if you were running them manually.

The various `subprocess` calls give you a variety of ways to deal with the output of each script.  You could just let the output flow to the console, or you could redirect the output to either a single file, or to a file for each script.

You could get fancy and rather than hard-coding the names/paths of each script file, you could put them in a subdirectory, list that subdirectory in your wrapper, and allow any script dropped into the subdirectory to be run with this wrapper tool.

Comment: Great.  This method avoids any collisions of variable names, method names and such, and also gives you some great options for dealing with the output.  See my addition for another idea.

Comment: Thank u for inputs